# How to stop a form from submitting until an ajax function, that was called by onSubmit, has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

My code is below. I want the form to submit until after the ajax function has finished, that way the `submit` variable can be set properly. But `submit` always has the defaulted `false` value. How do I get the form to wait until the ajax call is completed and the `submit` variable is given a new value?

```js
$("#CreateCandidateForm").on('submit', function (event) {
    var theFirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
    var theLastName = $("#LastName").val();
    var submit = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CreateSearch", // the method we are calling
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ firstName: theFirstName, lastName: theLastName }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == false) {
                submit = true;
            }                     
        },
        error: function (exception) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(exception);
            alert('Exception: ' + exception);        
        }
    });    
    return submit;
});
```

Comment: You have to use async: true when make ajax call

Comment: Run ajax post first, if result is true `$('#yourFormId').submit();` can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery.when()** Provides a way to execute callback functions based on zero or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

It will set the submit = true when the ajax requests is successful.

```
$.when( $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "CreateSearch", 
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: JSON.stringify({ firstName: theFirstName, lastName: theLastName })

       })).then( 

           function(result ){ // Success function
             if (result == false) {
                 submit = true;
             }

           },function(exception){ // failure function
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log(exception);
                alert('Exception: ' + exception);  
         });
```

Comment: So the create candidate form does in fact wait for the ajax CreateSearch call to finish, however, the value of submit does not change. I have tried leaving "return submit" after the .when().then, and having it in the success part of the .then() and same result

Answer (score 0):

Hi as i understood you need the submit set to true only when you get response from the server inside the result function , jQuery now defines a 'when' function for this purpose.

You may see the full answer in this question and use it for your ajax request :

[Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done)

```
 $.when(ajax1()).done(function(a1){
  //a1 includes ajax1 response
    submit=true;
 });

 function ajax1() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "someUrl",
    dataType: "json",
    data:  yourJsonData,            
    ...
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just always `return false;`. This will always prevent the submit.

You can then submit it in the success callback:

```
success: function (result) {
    if (!result) {
        $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    }                     
}
```

Don't forget to unbind the submit to prevent an infinite loop.

You should also remove the `event.preventDefault()` since you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Sounds good, I tried it but still didn't work, don't know why, `ajax` just doesn't seem to work in `onsubmit` event.